# jcarousel problem at 16th click on next

Tags: jquery-plugins, jcarousel

I use jCarousel, with prev/next button as image.

```
    function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {

    jQuery('#mycarousel-next').bind('click', function() {
        carousel.next();
        return false;
    });

    jQuery('#mycarousel-prev').bind('click', function() {
        carousel.prev();
        return false;
    });
};

// Ride the carousel...
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#mycarousel").jcarousel({
        scroll: 1,
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
        // This tells jCarousel NOT to autobuild prev/next buttons
        buttonNextHTML: null,
        buttonPrevHTML: null
    });
});
```

I have 21 image (). If I start to click on next button, all is right until the 16th click.
At 16th click on next button, images scrolls back of 3 images.

Any clue?
Alberto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've just found the solution, and it's really interesting.
just upgrade your jquery to the latest version.

jquery prior to 1.5 have this confirmed bug.

$.fn.animate cannot "start" from any value less than -10000
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7193

the reason it's the 16th image is:
10.000/16 = 625px. 
10.000/17 = 588px

your images are sized between 588-625px right?

best,
alp